# IE7 cookies not sticking on browser close. Could it be P3P? How the cookie is set in the Java?

Tags: session, cookies, internet-explorer-7, sticky, p3p

I'm having difficulty with getting cookies to stick in IE7. Whenever the browser is closed, the cookie is cleared or not remember when I bring up a new window. I'm have a bad time trying to find the right answer on Google, so I was wondering if anyone could help me out or refer me to a place on the Web with an answer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

In general, w3schools is the first place I go.